# How to insert a new element, so that it shows in the right style (with jQuery)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm pretty new in programming in general, so my question may be easy to answer or even stupid, but here I go:

When adding a new Button (or any element) into my Site, this button doesn't show in the right style. What am I doing wrong?

Code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />

<script>
$(function() {
$( "#accordion" ).accordion();
});

 $(function() {
$( "button" )
.button()
.click(function() {
$('#panel').append("<button>OK?</button>");
});
});
</script>

</head>
  <body>
    <button>Go!</button>
    <div id="accordion">
       <h3>Heading 1</h3>
        <div>
          <p id="panel">
        Text
          </p>
        </div>                  
    </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "this button doesn't show in the right style"?

Comment: unfortunately, we can't sniff into "/resources/demos/style.css". show your styles please

Comment: Sorry, I try to be more precise: The first button ('Go!') is shown like a button in jQuery-UI style ... The other button ('OK?'), which is added through clicking on the first, just looks like a 'normal' html button without any styles. I hope that explains my problem better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code after you appending the button OK:

```
 $('#panel').append("<button>OK?</button>");
 $( "#panel button" ).button();
```

Comment: Thx for the fast answer, but that didn't help. The second button still shows wrong...

Comment: It should. Where did you place it exactly?

Comment: Try: $('#panel').append("<button>OK?</button>");$( "#panel button" ).button( "refresh" );

Comment: Sorry...no need of refresh : $('#panel').append("<button>OK?</button>");     $( "#panel button" ).button();

Answer (score 0):

I tested your issue. The reason for the two different button styles is the line

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
```

where you import the jquery-ui.css styling. This actually alooks at where a button is in a page, and styles them differently. As the second button ('OK?') is withing a panel, it recieves a different style.

You can try your example with the above line commented out - it will still work (without the styling) and the two buttons will look exactly the same.

So this is really **not a jQuery issue**, but only an issue with **CSS** styling. If you want to dive into this deeper I suggest you look at your page in either *Chrome JS Console* or *Firefox Firebug*. Both will tell you why each element on the page looks exactly as it does, i.e. they will tell you if the button styling comes from `jquery-ui.css` or `style.css`.

---

*Note that I obviously had no access to* `/resources/demos/style.css` *so I removed that line for my test. A further suggestion from me is to check the two styles you import for competing style definitions, e.g. one style says buttons should be styled like this, and the other says something different.*

Comment: That's right, indeed. But I want the 2 buttons look in the jQuery-UI Style and not in the standard html way, so commenting out that line won't do the trick. But thx again for the fast answer ;)

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience with jQuery UI, but I think you should add the correct styling classes to elements for jQuery UI to style them appropriately. If you add `class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only"` to your added button, it will show up with the right styling. But this might not be the right way to do it, I admit.

Comment: This solution works, you are right, but i was looking for another solution. Thx anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the right solution, but I can suggest a workaround. 
Inscpect what classes jquery them ui adds to the 'Go' button and while appending the 'OK' button, add those classes to the OK button

Something like this.

```
$('#panel').append("<button class="jquery ui theme button classes">OK?</button>");
```

Comment: This works, but is not the solution I'm looking for, thx anyway ;)